# Bundle Metadata weirdness when changing a Bundle Type

Tags: 2013, bundles, metadata

**Issue**:
When I copy and paste a bundle and change the Bundle Type (to a schema that uses some of the same metadata field names), the GUI reports that the metadata is not correct.

**Example**:

2 Bundles. 
2 Bundle Types:

- BundleType_X
- BundleType_Y

BundleType_Y has 2 metadata fields

- *test1*
- test2

BundleType_X has 2 metadata fields

- *test1*
- test3

Create a Bundle on BundleType_X and popualted *test1*

Copy and pasted Bundle opened, seems OK

Update Title and receive an error (see below) informing me the metadata is in error; visual review shows the metadata is present and seemingly correct.

I need to update the metadata (add space and remove space is fine) for the Bundle to save!

Is this expected / explainable?

[image]

### Additional Info / example:

Further to this I also wrote out the Bundle.Metadata using the core service and it appears fine in there too - is this a GUI bug perhaps?

As the image below shows, the third item, copied and pasted - returns (via the core service request) the populated and seemingly correct metadata XML.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any evidence to the contrary of this being a GUI bug. It's not something that's a show-stopper for us and we have educated users of the 'tweak' to force the GUI 'update' to the metadata items in the *edge cases* that arise.

It's something that we don't feel warrants the implementation of another hotfix unless it's observed in Web8 when we upgrade.